# Replacement of laptop screen, back light issue

Tags: display, hardware-failure, backlight

I have laptop with broken screen.

When I accidentally broke the screen it shattered with cracks, and everything went white with some colorful stripes but after some minutes screen started to flicker and then went out totally black. I thought that I will replace led matrix and it will work, so I ordered screen specific for my laptop, however resolution of this screen was a bit higher (it was HD but I got full HD). Number of pins (30 pins) , size and connector position is the same. This display is without separate back-light connector.

I changed matrix but when I powered op PC there was no back-light, I just faintly saw my desktop.

The question si:

- Do you think that PC have something wrong internal because after display cracking screen was flickering and then went out? SO maybe due shortage?
- Do you think that different resolution have some impact on back-light?
- Have somebody encountered similar issue?

Answer (score 0):

You asked:

> ...Do you think that PC have something wrong internal...

but you failed to mention how the screen was broken in the first place. So the answer there is:

- If you hit just the screen and cracked it, then it's unlikely.
- If you dropped the laptop from the top of a building and cracked the screen, then it's very likely.

Also, it seems to me that you've already answered your own question...

> ...resolution of this screen was a bit higher
>
> ...This display is without separate back-light connector...
>
> ...when I powered op PC there was no back-light...

The answer is that you've obviously purchased the wrong screen for your laptop. Look for the model number on the back of your old LCD/LED screen and order a new screen with the same model number.